# Time series forecasting using statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

So here I am attempting to forecast a year worth of values in a timeseries (`ts`), using arima model but I can't actually get the forecasted values', the predicted values are somewhat in different scale (you can see the last one from the dataset is 339 and the predicted are very small) but I am not sure where to tweak the code. I was trying to change `fill_value` to different value but I don't know if this is proper method. 
I suppose this might also have something to do with this line:

```
predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(ts_log.ix[0], index=ts_log.index)
```

Is there a way to extend the index to cover forecasted values?

The code is below:

```
ts_log = np.log(ts)
ts_log_diff = ts_log - ts_log.shift()

model = ARIMA(ts_log, order=(2, 1, 2))
results_ARIMA = model.fit(disp=-1)
plt.plot(ts_log_diff)
plt.plot(results_ARIMA.fittedvalues, color='red')
plt.title('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_ARIMA.fittedvalues-ts_log_diff)**2))

predictions_ARIMA_diff = pd.Series(results_ARIMA.predict('1949-02-01','1961-12-01'), copy=True)
predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum = predictions_ARIMA_diff.cumsum()
predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(ts_log.ix[0], index=ts_log.index)
predictions_ARIMA_log = predictions_ARIMA_log.add(predictions_ARIMA_diff_cumsum,fill_value=0)
predictions_ARIMA = np.exp(predictions_ARIMA_log)

plt.plot(ts)
plt.plot(predictions_ARIMA)
plt.title('RMSE: %.4f'% np.sqrt(sum((predictions_ARIMA-ts)**2)/len(ts)))
```

So here you can see how the results look, first one is the last value I have and beginning with `1961-01-01` I have predicted values.

```
1960-12-01    339.216967
1961-01-01      3.111950
1961-02-01      3.295407
1961-03-01      3.540066
1961-04-01      3.789093
1961-05-01      3.980322
1961-06-01      4.068641
1961-07-01      4.045327
1961-08-01      3.939715
1961-09-01      3.802622
1961-10-01      3.684713
1961-11-01      3.622262
1961-12-01      3.632668
```

Comment: Use the `typ="level"` keyword in predict if the ARIMA has differencing.

Comment: Hmm,  but is that predict used in right place?

1961-12-01    6.511897e+64  Now this is so small that the chart is invisblew after using that :/

Comment: Do you know Maybe better way to do the forecasting on the given time series?